# Python cross platform os.system

Tags: python

currently my Python program opens a text file like this:

```
os.system('gedit decryptedText.txt&')
```

Now, I presume this will not work on Windows, since gedit is a Linux application? How can I make this run on both Windows and Linux. Or will it work on both?

Comment: if sys.platform == 'win32': os.system('START notepad blabla'), elif platform == 'linux2'...

Answer (score 4):

Check for OS first, and assign depending on result?

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    os.system('notepad ecryptedText.txt&')
elif os.name == 'posix':
    os.system('gedit decryptedText.txt&')
```

Comment: do I use if os.name =='nt' or 'win32'?

Comment: test it out on your system. I just ran it on both my windows and my ubuntu box. os.name came up as 'nt' and 'posix' respectively :)

Comment: okay. and just to clarify, for the windows one is it os.system('notepad ecryptedText.txt&') OR os.system('START notepad blabla')

Comment: notepad is automatically in the path for windows installations. You do not need to do START notepad unless for some crazy reason you lost a crucial bit of path.

Answer (score 4):

On MS Windows you could use [os.startfile(filename)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile) for file types that have associated editors.

Hence your full solution would be something like:

```
def start_file(filename):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.startfile(filename)
    else:
        os.system('gedit %s&' % filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work on both, obviously, since gedit is the standard editor for the universe.

Kidding. It will not work, since you are essentially launching a specific application, only available on certain platforms (Linux). You could configure your default editor start command in a configuration file and use it to compose your command string.

Comment: To nitpick, gedit may very well work on Windows if it only depends on GTK+ or something. Of course, that doesn't mean anyone actually uses it there.